# Connect-MgGraph with managed identity in Azure Automation produces an error

Tags: azure, automation, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell, azure-managed-identity

I am using a system managed identity in an Azure Automation account. Separately, I gave the identity (Application) all the Graph access it requires. I am leveraging the Az module to get the access token, which I then pass to connect-mggraph. Natively, the MgGraph module does not yet support the managed identity natively.

Here is the code I am using to attempt the connection. My expectation is that the "connect-mgraph" will succeed using the managed identity.

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$token = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token.token
```

This is the returned error:

```
   3 |  Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token.token
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0,
     | Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6xxxxxxxx'. The system cannot
     | find the file specified.
Get-MgGroup_List: C:\Temp\jka4ters.qmd\f1cc4605-9c45-4b6e-a89a-xxxxxxxxxxxx.ps1:5
```

I've tried various minor alterations to the code, but always get the same error. Others seem to have success with this online. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

*Initially I tried the same commands in automation(powershel-7.1) and got same error.*

**Console:**

[image]

Instead of using  **`-ResourceTypeName MSGraph`** I have used  **`-ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com"`** in  below commands.
Also please ensure that you have using both **`module and runbook`** in same runtimeversion.

```
#Connect to Microsoft Graph within Azure Automation
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$token = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com"
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token.Token
```

After I executed above commands the **`MgGraph`** is connected successfully.

**Console:**

[image]